# Contractions and Extensions of Ideals and Faithful Flatness

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, flatness

Let $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ be rings with $B$ a faithfully flat $A$-module and $C$ a faithfully flat $B$-module which is an integral extension of $B$. Given a maximal ideal $I \subseteq C$, is it true that
$$(I \cap A)B = I \cap B$$
I know that faithful flatness is transitive and also gives $(I \cap B)C = I$. I feel like this is true, but have been unable to prove it.

Comment: Are the rings in question all Noetherian?

Comment: $A$ is Noetherian but $B$ and $C$ are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faithful flatness implies that contraction is *left* inverse to extension of ideals, I think you had that backwards. In other words $IC \cap B = I$ for faithfully flat extensions, but not $(I\cap B)C = I$.

For a counterexample to your question, consider $k \subseteq k[x^2] \subseteq k[x]$ and the maximal ideal $xk[x]$.  This also shows that even for the finite faithfully flat extension $k[x^2] \subseteq k[x]$, contraction of ideals is not left inverse to extension.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. Do you know of an equivalent condition for which $(I \cap B)C = I$? I know this is equivalent to the algebra morphism $B \to C$ being surjective but do not know any others.

Comment: @AustinShiner No, it's not equivalent to the morphism being surjective.  As far as I know it is a delicate property, typical of epimorphisms.  For example if $B \rightarrow C$ is an epimorphism, then extension is left inverse to contraction if additionally either (1) $B \rightarrow C$ is finite (i.e. surjective); or (2) $B \rightarrow C$ is flat.

Comment: @ Badam Baplan Why is it not equivalent to the homomorphism $f: B \to C$ being surjective? The contraction ideal is defined to be $f^{-1}(I)$ and the extension ideal would then be $f(f^{-1}(I))$. If $f$ is surjective then $f(f^{-1}(S)) = S$ for any set $S$, and in particular, $f(f^{-1}(I)) = I$. Where did I go wrong in this?

Comment: @Austin Shiner You have correctly observed that surjective morphisms have the property in question.  However, that doesn't establish that the property in question is *equivalent* to being surjective, and indeed, it is not.  For example, a consequence of (2) in my previous comment is that localizations have the property in question, and localizations are typically not surjective.